# How to Pass the Failure test data to soft assert in java selenium

Tags: java, selenium

I have a test data in a json file which looks like below -

```
{
    "alerts" : [
    {
        "alert_name" : "employee",
        "sql_query" : "select * from employee",
        "description" : "Query with Variables",
        "default_interval" : "10 minutes",
        "default_priority" : "Critical",
        "variables" : [{
                            "variable" : "failurereason",
                            "value" : "INVALID USER"
                            },
                            {
                            "variable" : "count",
                            "value" : "1"
                    }]
        },
    {
        "alert_name" : "employee2",
        "sql_query" : "select * from employee2",
        "description" : "Query with Variables",
        "default_interval" : "10 minutes",
        "default_priority" : "Critical",
        "variables" : [{
                            "variable" : "failurereason",
                            "value" : "INVALID USER"
                            },
                            {
                            "variable" : "count",
                            "value" : "1"
                    }]
        }
```

I have a test method in java selenium which will iterate through the json and check with the actual data if the data exists or not.Below is the Java selenium method.

```
public boolean createAlert(String jsonFile,String Host, String Port) {
        boolean success = true;
        String logStr = "Unable to create Alert";
        
        JSONObject readJsonFilePath = rjf.readJsonFilePath(jsonFile);
        JSONArray alertsJsonArray = readJsonFilePath.getJSONArray("alerts");
        
        System.out.println("+++++ Number of Test Cases to be run are : " + alertsJsonArray.length() + " +++++");
        
        for(int i = 0; i < alertsJsonArray.length(); i++)
        {
            JSONObject alertJsonObject = alertsJsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            String description = alertJsonObject.getString("description");
            System.out.println("+++++++++++Test Case : " + i + " Running : " + description + " ++++++++++++++");
            
            String alert_name = alertJsonObject.getString("alert_name");
            String sql_query = alertJsonObject.getString("sql_query");
            String defaultInterval = alertJsonObject.getString("default_interval");
            String defaultPriority = alertJsonObject.getString("default_priority");
            
            if (
                    this.clickUponCreate(alert_name,sql_query) &&
                    this.setVariablesInVariableBar(alertJsonObject,"variables") &&
                    this.runQueryCreateAlertAndVerifyIsAlertCreated(alert_name, Host, Port, defaultInterval, defaultPriority))
            {   
                logStr = "Able to set the values ";
            }
            else {
                System.out.println(TEXT_RED +  alert_name + description + "Test Case : " + i + " Failed");
                success=false;
            }
          }
        System.out.println(logStr);
        return success;
    }
```

Above code loops twice because the json object has two test data, now if one of the test fails at the end it just mentions the test failed because its added in the else condition.

And i have used soft assert like below -

```
softassert.assertTrue(page.createAlert(jsonFile,Host,Port),
                "test11.1: Verified combinations of Alerts");
```

I am not getting which one of the two test data set from json file are failing.
After the run if one of it failing it just mentions "verified test should be true but it is false"

Say if i have 100 test data similarly how to identify which one test data that is failed from json test data set. Is there a way ?

Comment: There is a lot of json stuff but not a single line of Selenium calls. Why are you tagging your question with selenium tag?

Answer (score 0):

There are two way to achieve this:

**1) By using `SoftAssert`.**

What you can do is add a message in the soft assertion to identify which test case is getting failed. As per the code i can see you are printing the test case number and the description.

```
  softassert.assertTrue(page.createAlert(jsonFile,Host,Port),
                "test11.1: Verified combinations of Alerts", 
                "Test Case : " + i + " Failed : " + description);
```

**2) The correct way to do it would be by using dataprovider:** By using the dataprovider you can execute the test method as per the available test data and even if one test method fail, other will get executed. Hence your code will not get break.

***Note: Please change and correct code & logic as per your need.***

```
@DataProvider
    public Object[][] getJsonData(){
       return createAlert("","","");
    }


 @Test(dataProvider = "jsonData")
    public void testJson(String alert_name, String sql_query, String defaultInterval, String defaultPriority){
        //Add your logic here
    }



 public Object[][] createAlert(String jsonFile, String Host, String Port) {
        boolean success = true;
        String logStr = "Unable to create Alert";

        JSONObject readJsonFilePath = rjf.readJsonFilePath(jsonFile);
        JSONArray alertsJsonArray = readJsonFilePath.getJSONArray("alerts");


        System.out.println("+++++ Number of Test Cases to be run are : " + alertsJsonArray.length() + " +++++");

        Object[][] jsonData = new Object[alertsJsonArray.length()][4];

        for(int i = 0; i < alertsJsonArray.length(); i++)
        {
            JSONObject alertJsonObject = alertsJsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            String description = alertJsonObject.getString("description");
            System.out.println("+++++++++++Test Case : " + i + " Running : " + description + " ++++++++++++++");

            String alert_name = alertJsonObject.getString("alert_name");
            String sql_query = alertJsonObject.getString("sql_query");
            String defaultInterval = alertJsonObject.getString("default_interval");
            String defaultPriority = alertJsonObject.getString("default_priority");

            jsonData[i][0] = alert_name;
            jsonData[i][1] = sql_query;
            jsonData[i][2] = defaultInterval;
            jsonData[i][3] = defaultPriority;

        }
        System.out.println(logStr);
        return jsonData;
    }
```